# How to list and isolate the non-repetitive nodes with xsl:text in xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

this is my xslt

```
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:call-template name="h-contents">
                <xsl:with-param name="Response" select="Response" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template name="h-contents">
            <xsl:param name="Response" />
            <xsl:call-template name="h-BaggageAllowanceTableforDP">
                <xsl:with-param name="Response" select="$Response"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="h-BaggageAllowanceTableforDP">
            <xsl:param name="Response"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$Response/Itinerary/MMBItinerary/FlightSegment[BookingFlightSegment/CarrierName != 'Kingfisher']" mode="otherAirlinesLinksforDP" />


        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template match="MMBFlightSegment" mode="otherAirlinesLinksforDP">
            <xsl:variable name="opName" select="BookingFlightSegment/CarrierName"/>
            <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[BookingFlightSegment/CarrierName=$opName])">
                <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()" />

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$position=1">
                        <xsl:text>**</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$opName"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$opName"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>    
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I am expecting the output in this format the first CarrierName should start with '**' the last with 'and' and the remaining should be amended with ',' for all CarrierName not eqalling to Kingfisher

output: **CityFlyer, China Airlines and Air India

and my actual input is as follows

```
    <Response>
        <Itinerary>
            <MMBItinerary>
                <FlightSegment>
                    <BookingFlightSegment>
                        <CarrierName>CityFlyer</CarrierName>
                    </BookingFlightSegment> 
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment>
                    <BookingFlightSegment>
                        <CarrierName>Kingfisher</CarrierName>
                    </BookingFlightSegment> 
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment>
                    <BookingFlightSegment>
                        <CarrierName>China Airlines</CarrierName>
                    </BookingFlightSegment> 
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment>
                    <BookingFlightSegment>
                        <CarrierName>Air India</CarrierName>
                    </BookingFlightSegment> 
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment>
                    <BookingFlightSegment>
                        <CarrierName>Kingfisher</CarrierName>
                    </BookingFlightSegment> 
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment>
                    <BookingFlightSegment>
                        <CarrierName>CityFlyer</CarrierName>
                    </BookingFlightSegment> 
                </FlightSegment>
            </MMBItinerary>
        </Itinerary>
    </Response>
```

Comment: I couldn't get the count of the list so not able to perform more than 2 operations in <xsl:choose>

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to get a distinct list of carriers (or, if your processor supports it, use an extension function), instead of the awkward (and inefficient) method of checking preceding siblings.

Once you have that, the rest is pretty trivial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="seg-by-carier" match="BookingFlightSegment" use="CarrierName" />

<xsl:template match="/Response">
    <xsl:text>**</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="FlightSegment/BookingFlightSegment[count(. | key('seg-by-carier', CarrierName)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="CarrierName" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position()=last() - 1"> and </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that in your attempt, the `position()` function returns the position of the current node in the entire selected node-set, including the duplicates. So that within your `xsl:if` condition, the test `position()=last()` would never return true (unless there are no duplicates).

Comment: Thanks Mike for your valuable code, however I need to filter the CarrierName which are not equal to Kingfisher in this case. Also this grouping logic is working correctly in local, when this is deployed on to the server the key is not fetched correctly and the carriernames are not processed and displayed

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean. The above returns the expected output when applied to your input. If you're getting a different result, then your processor is not conforming to the XSLT specification. If you need a different result, edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: have attached my actual input and the code which I tried initially, I need to filter the CarrierName which are not equal to Kingfisher and perfrom the insolating logic.

Comment: The required adjustment is trivial and you should able to make it yourself.